# Django Custom User Admin Login

Tags: python, django, authentication, admin

I'm creating a custom user by extending the AbstractBaseUser class. I have read the Django documentation and several tutorials online and I think that what I've done till now is very basic and should work.

The problem I'm facing is that even if I create a new DB from scratch and do a syncdb, the manage.py console **does not ask me for a admin username and password** (as it usually does). Hence, I cannot access /admin.

The problem is partially (and wrongly) resolved my using AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE instead of AUTH_USER_MODEL. This however leads to 'Users' and 'MyUser' being showed as different objects on the admin page i.e. MyUser is not set as the default user. (obviously)

**models.py**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, corp, password=None):
        if not (username or email or corp):
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username, email and corporation')
        user = self.model(username=username, email=UserManager.normalize_email(email), corp=corp, )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, corp, password):
        user = self.create_user(self, username, email, corp,
                                password=password, )
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    corp = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name="is_employee_of")

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username + "@" + self.corp.shortName

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'corp']
```

**admin.py**

```
admin.site.register(Client)
admin.site.register(Address)

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'corp', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'corp', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_admin', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal Info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'corp')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_staff')}),
        ('Important Dates', {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

    search_fields = ('username',)
    ordering = ('username',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'Profiles',
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Profiles.MyUser"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, but perhaps you can use fixtures  to load initial data:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Then, when your model is created, it will automatically be populated with 1 value for the first admin.

Comment: This looks like a smart hack. I will try it but it still won't tell me why I'm facing this problem in the first place. The same error could cause more problems in the future too.